# How do I escape backslashes in a sed script embedded in a bash script

Tags: bash, sed, escaping

I want to edit a file via a sed script in a bash script. I want this to be easy to maintain later; easy to understand and modify. The replacement string looks like:

```
PS1='\[\e[1;32m\][\u@\h \W]\$\[\e[0m\]'
```

In a perfect world, it would like this:

```
sed -i "s/^PS1.*$/PS1='\[\e[1;32m\][\u@\h \W]\$\[\e[0m\]'/g" /etc/skel/.bashrc
```

The problem is that bash and sed are stripping out the `\` giving the following result in the file:

```
PS1='[e[1;32m][@h W]$[e[0m]'
```

Obviously single quotes can't be used. A brute force solution is to use escapes, but for this to work I get a really ugly looking line:

```
sed -i "s/^PS1.*$/PS1='\\\\[\\\\e[1;32m\\\\][\\\\u@\\\\h \\\\W]\\\\$\\\\[\\\\e[0m\\\\]'/g" /etc/skel/.bashrc
```

I want the script to be readable and self contained (not using external files). Any alternatives to the above?

Comment: Use single quotes around anything like a regex unless you absolutely need some variable interpolated into the string.  Even then, use single quotes around most of the regex, and only use the double quotes around the part that must be interpolated. Using a made up example: `sed -e 's/\.\*'"$1"'\*\./ab'"$2"'c'\''d/' $3` or something along those lines. The sequence `'\''` is how you embed a single quote into the command line; the first single quote finishes the current single-quote section; the backslash-quote embeds a single quote into the string; the third single quote resumes the single quote.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bash's printf can add the necessary escapes, leaving the string to be inserted in an readable, editable form.

```
sed -i "s/^PS1.*$/$(printf "%q" "PS1='\[\e[1;32m\][\u@\h \W]$\[\e[0m\]'")/g" /etc/skel/.bashrc
```

Not trying to stick it all on one line makes the whole thing clearer.

```
REPL=$(printf "%q" "PS1='\[\e[1;32m\][\u@\h \W]$\[\e[0m\]'")
sed -i "s/^PS1.*$/$REPL/g" /etc/skel/.bashrc
```

Answer (score 4):

This might work for you:

```
echo "PS1=abc" |
sed 's/^PS1.*$/PS1='\''\\[\\e[1;32m\\][\\u@\\h \\W]\\$\\[\\e[0m\\]'\''/'
PS1='\[\e[1;32m\][\u@\h \W]\$\[\e[0m\]'
```

Comment: I find the single quotes difficult to pick out, plus the replacement string needs to be escaped which makes it a bit hard to read.

Answer (score 1):

Use a sed script file with `sed -f`. This alternative is not pretty, too, because it means having an additional file lying around, but at least you avoid shell escapes.

Comment: Don't want to use external files.

Comment: You can use a here document with some `sed` implementations, i.e. `sed -f - <<'EOF'`

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
sed -i 's/^PS1.*$/PS1=SINGLEQUOTESLASH[SLASHe[1;32mSLASH][SLASHu@SLASHh SLASHW]SLASH$SLASH[SLASHe[0mSLASH]SINGLEQUOTE/g' /etc/skel/.bashrc
sed -i "s/SINGLEQUOTE/'/g" /etc/skel/.bashrc
sed -i "s/SLASH/\\/g" /etc/skel/.bashrc
```

Doing it in two passes is less efficient, but a few more microseconds is unnoticeable to most people.

Comment: I like where this is going but sed needs the \'s escaped... so it doesn't actualy produce the desired output.

Comment: @hauptmech I've edited it to use SLASH instead of `\`. Looks a little less legible now though. You may be better off using python, or perl