# Sed replace on bashrc with hostname variables and double quoted

Tags: bash, sed, escaping

I'm tired  to find a solution for sed substitution on /etc/bashrc

I like change the line

```
PS1="\u@\h NEW [\w]# "
```

for this

```
PS1="\u@\h.hostname.com NEW [\w]# "
```

where hostname.com

```
HOST=$(hostname)
```

Try several sustituions, wiht escape \ but nothing.

Also see another question, [How do I escape backslashes in a sed script embedded in a bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8713201/how-do-i-escape-backslashes-in-a-sed-script-embedded-in-a-bash-script) but I'm lost.

Usually I use "" for use ${VARIABLE} but don't work, also if use \ for escape

```
sed -i "s/^PS1.*$/PS1=\"\\u@\\h.${HOST}\ \[\\w\]#\ \"/g" /etc/bashrc
```

Comment: Why on Earth would you want to edit your `/etc/bashrc` with `sed`?  If you want a particular `PS1` value there, just add it at the end; that will override any previous value.

Comment: And by the by your system-wide default prompt should probably use `\$` as the prompt character, not a hard-coded `#`, which implies root privileges to most Unix-literate users -- it could be very misleading.

Answer (score 2):

Use `\H` if you want the complete hostname in your prompt. Then you wouldn't have to worry about this `sed` substitution.

Change your `PS1` to:

```
PS1="\u@\H NEW [\w]# "
```

If you want to use `sed`, the following command should work:

```
sed 's/\(^.*\h\)\(.*$\)/\1.'"$HOST"'\2/g' /etc/bashrc
```

Comment: Thanks but question it's not about \H or bashrc substitution, it's about sed problem with sustitutions. Same if I like replace original PS1 ask it's the same.

Answer (score 0):

After several test, I've got a solution.

```
HOST=$(hostname); sed -i "s/^PS1.*$/PS1=\"\\\u@\\\h.${HOST}\ \[\\\w\]#\ \"/g" /etc/bashrc
```

Afert read comment from user dogbane y change to

```
sed -i "s/^PS1.*$/PS1=\"\\\u@\\\H\ \[\\\w\]#\ \"/g" /etc/bashrc
```

Thanks...

Comment: If you don't require interpolation, you could single-quote the string and get away with just the single backslashes.